# security issues on displaying pdf documents by uiwebview

Tags: ios, security, pdf, uiwebview

I use UIWebView to display pdf documents in my app. I read somewhere that UIWebView can present some vulnerabilities in terms of security; but I didn't understand if my encrypted pdf's can be stolen using these vulnerabilities. Should I quit to use UIWebView to protect my pdf's?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Quicklook Framework for displaying pdf as preview.

Use this nice tutorial for using this framework : [preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: At this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917368/display-encrypted-file-using-quicklook-framework-or-uidocumentinteractioncontrol; someone wrote that "QLPreviewController is using UIWebView underneath, and calls the loadRequest: to load the requested file."